# Color normalization results in gray tones

Tags: c, opengl

I am currently writing an raycaster and I wanted to add textures to my walls, but an color error holds me back.

I use floating point numbers in my C code to represent colors, but the graphic I am using is in the rgb byte format. I get the error when using the normalized floating point values. Loaded with the following code everything works correctly (but using the undesired rgb byte functions):

```
    //... glfw window initialization...
    for (int y = 0; y < 32; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 32; x++)
        {
            int p = (y * 32 + x) * 3;
            float r = rgb[p];
            float g = rgb[p + 1];
            float b = rgb[p + 2];

            glColor3ub(r, g, b);
            glPointSize(16);
            glBegin(GL_POINTS);
            glVertex2i(x * 16, y * 16);
            glEnd();
        }
    }
```

Resulting in:

[image]

The error occurs if I try to normalize the bytes (one by one) with the following code:

```
    //... glfw window initialization...
    for (int y = 0; y < 32; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 32; x++)
        {
            int p = (y * 32 + x) * 3;
            float r = ((float)rgb[p]) / 255.0f;
            float g = ((float)rgb[p + 1]) / 255.0f;
            float b = ((float)rgb[p + 2]) / 255.0f;

            glColor3f(r,g, b);
            glPointSize(16);
            glBegin(GL_POINTS);
            glVertex2i(x * 16, y * 16);
            glEnd();
        }
    }
```

The picture loaded this way has different colors:
[image: The wrong result]

Comment: no, value can be 0 to 255.

Comment: I was asking how the array is actually defined, not what values you put in it. Might make a difference in the case if `rgb[]` is signed. In the first case its a conversion to `float` *and back*, but the second would be scaling the wrong value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose the array `rbg[]` is `signed`, and consider a red component value `255`.

In the first example the `255` is actually `-1` and is converted to `-1.000000` and this is then passed to the function after converting to type `GLubyte` which is unsigned 8-bit. The conversion rules will make this value `255` which is what you thought you had.

In the second example the `255` is again converted to `-1.000000` and scaled to be `-0.003922` instead of the expected `1.000000`and so the result is very different from what you expected.

The solution is to define the array as `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`.